# "Or"-ing two Options in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-option

I want to do something like this:

```
def or[A](x: Option[A], y: Option[A]) = x match {
 case None => y   
 case _ => x 
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this? The best I can come up with was `Seq(x, y).flatten.headOption`

Comment: [`orElse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.Option) is not sufficient?

Comment: The [source of `orElse`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L256), just for reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's already defined for `Option`:

```
def or[A](x: Option[A], y: Option[A]) = x orElse y
```

Answer (score 2):

in scalaz, you can use the Plus typeclass for this:

```
scala> 1.some <+> 2.some
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> none[Int] <+> 2.some
res2: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> none[Int] <+> none[Int]
res3: Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you don't want to use [orElse](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.Option), well, there's always another way to do it in Scala.

```
def or[A](xOpt: Option[A], yOpt: Option[A]) = xOpt.map(Some(_)).getOrElse(yOpt)
```